# Is there any point in having dependencies declared in a pom of type "pom"?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm working with a pom that is of type "pom".  If the pom is the only thing being deployed, I don't see what dependencies matter.  There are no child poms of this pom.  If there were children, those might be inheriting the dependencies, but there are no projects inheriting these dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right. But you can always use that pom file as the parent. Say you decided to write a new maven module later. you can use the above mentioned pom file as the parent pom. So by specifying dependencies versions, you can influence child module writer to use your poms dependency versions.

But this is a exceptional case. The point is, that it is not a must to specify childs in the parent pom. There can be childs that refers the pom as the parent without parent knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven best practice page describes an example where you would extract all the persistent dependencies into a separate pom of packaging type pom.

You can then add this pom as a dependency in all projects that require a persistent element and they would inherit all of it's dependencies.

See here:
http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

When you see a pom with pom packaging - don't just look for poms that extend this one. Look for poms that include this as a dependency.